# Is it possible to design a DTO only return partial API response?

Tags: dto

I am writing a responseDTO as a return for API call with Springboot and Java. I simplify the api response for easy interpretation, it is like the following.

```
{"Summary":{
    "a": 0，
    “b": 1,
    "c": 2,
    "d": 3,
    "e" :4}
}
```

My question is: can I construct a DTO with only two keys like this, skipping some keys?

````
public class SummaryDto {
  private String a;
  private String b;
}```



I tried, seems it does not work, got empty reponse. Any advice is hugely appreciated! Or if you find some good reference, I would like to read it too!
````

Comment: If what you mean is: Can you construct a DTO without having to return all the keys? Yes, any null key will not be part of the response.

Comment: @estebanrincon Thank you! Let met try again!

Comment: @estebanrincon Thank you! it worked as you described! I have posted another questions, and also looking forward to your advice if you are interested!